# How to use jQuery.insertAfter after a TextNode?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Let's say I have this HTML.

```
<h1>View Assignment Description
  <span class="nav-teacher">
  </span>
</h1>
```

I want to insert some HTML right after the text within the `h1` tag. How do I select that text and use it as the parameter for jQuery.insertAfter?

I know I could just select the class `nav-teacher` and use insertBefore, but I have multiple pages with this header tag and not every page has the same span with class `nav-teacher` after it, and I'd like to keep my code as DRY as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) to get the text nodes

```
$("h1").contents().eq(0).after("<span>Hello</span>");
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NSQ88/)